# Sublime folding control?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

If a function accepts a lot of options I find it much easier to read it if I split those in few lines, like this code in python:

```
def fun( param1 = 'this',
         param2 = 'and that',
         param3 = 'and this too', ## because today is Wednesday
         param5 = 'I think you got the point' ):

    print "You can't fold me! I AM PURE EVIL"
```

Unfortunately then sublime will fold only the bracket with options, not the next following code. Is there a way to set-up sublime so that the body of the function would be folded instead?

I am using sublime2, OS X system

Comment: In just core sublime you can select text and use the key shortcut for folding (Shift+Ctrl+[ or Alt+Command+[ on MacOS) to fold it. I don't think you can make the default fold arrows in the gutter take more text into account though. Possibly a plugin could implement something like that on its own, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text folding works on indention, so everything in the next level is indented.

Something like this does work.

```
def fun(
    param1 = 'this',
    param2 = 'and that',
    param3 = 'and this too', ## because today is Wednesday
    param5 = 'I think you got the point' ):

    print "You can't fold me! I AM PURE EVIL"
```

More control over the indention behaviour is something the plugin authors requested for a long time.